# Does uniform convergence of $f$ imply convergence of derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $X$ denote the collection of all differentiable functions $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$, such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'$ is continuous.

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence. By Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence, $f_n$ converges uniformly to some $f$.

Does that imply that $f'_n \rightarrow f'$ uniformly?

Comment: hi, Katestrophical, were you able to find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 4):

No!  Imagine the $f_n$ getting close to $f$ uniformly, but getting bumpier and bumpier.  You should be able to use this idea to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: As an idea, try looking at the sequence $f+\frac{1}{n}\phi(nx)$, where $\phi$ is a bounded function with derivative $1$ at $0$.

Comment: What if we flipped $f$ and $f'$ ?
$$$$
    Let $\{f'_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence. By Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence, $f'_n$ converges uniformly to some $f'$.

    Does that imply that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly?

Comment: Up to a constant, yes.  This is just fundamental theorem of calculus + interchanging integration and uniform limits.  Generally, integration behaves well numerically, differentiation does not.

Comment: @Katestrophical see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/214218/99325

Answer (score 2):

This is a counterexample. Take e.g. $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} (\sqrt{1+(n x)^2} - 1)$. We have that $f_n(0) = 0$, and $f'_n(x) = \dfrac{nx}{\sqrt{1+(nx)^2}}$ is continuous. We also have that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = |x|$, and
$$
|x| - f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n|x| + \sqrt{1 + (nx)^2}}\right)
$$
hence $0 \leq |x| - f_n(x) < \frac{1}{n}$ for every $x$, which implies that $f_n(x) \to |x|$ uniformly. On the other hand
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f'_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if $x>0$} \\
0 & \text{ if $x=0$} \\
-1 & \text{ if $x<0$} 
\end{cases}
$$
So we have that $f'_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions that converge to a discontinuous function, so its convergence cannot be uniform.