# Does uniform convergence of continuously differentiable $f_n$ imply point-wise convergence of derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n : [0, 1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a sequence of continuously differentiable functions, if $f_n \rightrightarrows f$. Can we conclude $f_n' \rightarrow f'$ pointwise?

I know there are many counterexamples for "uniform convergence" of derivatives, for example in this question: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3030110/549321)

If not, I really need a counterexample.

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is differentiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_n(x)=\frac1n\sin(nx)$, then $f_n\rightrightarrows0$. But $f_n'(x)=\cos(nx)$, and therefore $(f_n')_{n\in\Bbb N}$ does not converge pointwise to the null function.

Comment: It's a duplicate. Found quickly with a Google search for “pointwise convergence of derivatives site:math.stackexchange.com”

Comment: @MartinR Indeed. But this time I tried a lot to find a duplicate and I was unable to do it.