# Uniform limit of a sequence of bounded derivatives is a bounded derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-convergence

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of differentiable functions on $\mathbb R$ such that $f_n'$ is bounded for each $n$ ; if $\{f_n'\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $\mathbb R$ then is it true that $f$ is bounded and the derivative of some function ?

Answer (score 2):

Using $f$ as the limit of $f'_n$ is a little confusing, I will use $g$ as the limit function.

Let $h_n(x) = \int_0^x f'_n(t) dt$. Then $h_n(0) = 0$, and $h'_n = f'_n$.

Pick some interval $[a,b]$ that contains $0$. Using the result here [Uniform convergence of derivatives, Tao 14.2.7.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214218/27978) we
see that $h_n$ converge uniformly (on $[a,b]$) to some limit $h$ such that $h' = g$.

Since the interval was arbitrary, we see that $h'=g$ everywhere.

Boundedness follows from uniform convergence to $g$ and the fact that each 
$f'_n$ is bounded.

Comment: I think the interval $[a,b]$ should contain the point $x=0$ for which the sequence $h_n(0) \to 0=:L$. Otherwise, I like your solution.

Comment: @Svetoslav: That was my intent, thanks for catching that. The solution works anyway, but requires extra steps.

Comment: We don't know $f_n'$ is Riemann integrable. Fix: Use $h_n= f_n-f_n(0).$

Comment: @zhw.: We know that $f'_n$ is measurable and since it is bounded it is Lebesgue integrable. Also, the definition above gives the same value as in your comment.

Comment: Yes that's true, but why go through all that when you could just let $h_n = f_n-f_n(0)?$

Comment: @zhw.: True. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is indeed bounded. By uniform convergence, there is some $N$ such that $\forall x\in \mathbb R, |f(x)-f'_N(x)|\leq 1$.

Then $\forall x\in \mathbb R, |f(x)|\leq 1+|f'_N(x)|\leq 1+M_N$