# Give an example of the following or explain why it's impossible (Real Analysis):

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, uniform-continuity

A sequence $(f_n)$ of differentiable functions such that both $(f_n)$ and $(f'_n)$ converge uniformly but $f = \lim f_n$ is not differentiable at some point.

Thoughts so far:

We are taking the domain of these functions as all of $\mathbb{R}$.

I am under the impression that this request might be impossible since we can simply apply the Differentiable Limit Theorem. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: The theorem stated in this question seems to agree with you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214218/uniform-convergence-of-derivatives-tao-14-2-7