# $f_n\to f$ pointwisely, $f_n'\to g$ uniformly, then does $f'=g$ hold ? Do I use fundamental theorem of calculus correctly?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence

For each $n\in \mathbb N$, let $f_n:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be $C^1$.

Suppose

・$\forall x\in \mathbb R$ ; $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)= f(x)$

・$f'_n \to g$ uniformly.

Then, does $\bigg[$$f$ is $C^1$ on $\mathbb R$ and $f'=g \bigg]$ hold ?

I'm not sure whether the proof below works.

---

Fix $x\in \mathbb R$.

I have $f_n(x)=f_n(0)+\int_0^x f'_n (y) dy$.

Letting $n\to \infty$, I get $f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x g(y) dy \cdots (\ast)$ from the supposition.

From fundamental theorem of calculus, $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f'(x)=g(x)$.

But I wonder whether I used the theorem correctly or not.

Fundamental theorem of calculus is here.

---

**Fundamental Theorem of Calculus**

If $g$ is continuous on the interval $I\subset \mathbb R$, then $f(x):=\int_a^x g(y) dy$ is differentiable and $f'(x)=g(x)$ for all $x,a\in I.$

---

In $(\ast)$, $g$ is continuous due to the uniform convergence. But in this case, what plays the role of $I$ ? If I let $I=[-1, x+1]$, then $0,x\in I$, so does $I=[-1,x+1]$ work ?

---

**Postscript**

The similar problem is solved here [Uniform convergence of derivatives, Tao 14.2.7.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214218/uniform-convergence-of-derivatives-tao-14-2-7). This solved for $f_n : [a,b]\to \mathbb R.$

Now, I wonder whether this holds for $f_n: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214218/42969

Comment: I know the statement hold for $f_n:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$. I want to know whether this holds for $f_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R.$

Comment: Yes. For each $x$ choose $[a,b]$ such that $x\in[a,b]$. We don't have $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$, but we do have $f'=g$.